# How to store token in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a column in table with type character varying  here is the
query:

```
update logins 
set access_token='l38r8cfjm31b38ye91yjn1956vr3n74tc5sc0btholj0iain77' and uuid='123456789'  
where username = 'PWD_2006'
```

It give me the error:

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type boolean:  "l38r8cfjm31b38ye91yjn1956vr3n74tc5sc0btholj0iain77"
>   LINE 1: update logins set access_token='l38r8cfjm31b38ye91yjn1956vr3...
>                                              ^
>   SQL state: 22P02
>   Character: 32

Comment: Change `and` by a `,` (comma)

Answer (score 2):

Your query is interpreted as

```
... SET access_token =
        ('l38r8cfjm31b38ye91yjn1956vr3n74tc5sc0btholj0iain77'
         and uuid='123456789')
```

That is, `AND` is treated as a logical operator, and the string constant is interpreted as a `boolean` literal, which causes the error.

Replace `AND` with `,` like the comment suggests.